# How to check if ui-bootstrap-custom-tpls.js is required

Tags: jquery, angularjs, optimization, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

**Context:** I am optimizing a website that has been adding technical debt since 2015. The site loads a lot of stuff; JQuery and Angular.js, bootstrap.js and ui-bootstrap-custom-tpls.js. I think some of this stuff is not being used any longer.

**Goal:** Improve load time of a website by removing unused css and js.

**Issue:** `ui-bootstrap-custom-tpls-1.2.0.min.js` is loaded on every page. One or more pages *may* be using it. I'm not sure.

**QUESTION** -- How can I check if/where `ui-bootstrap-custom-tpls-1.2.0.min.js` is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check in respective controller for every page to make sure that you added dependency on ui-bootstrap on very top. if not then you are not using it for those pages
Ex:- [ui-bootstrap] in first line

Or if you used routers in angular then you can check for dependency requirement via manually removing form page and see if you are getting any error.

These might be little time consuming method , but that's how I would approach it